# Node typescript lacks a construct signature (new Buffer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, buffer

Im my node + typescript application I have the following code.

```
 const base64Data = new Buffer.from(url, 'base64');
```

Here it gives the following error.

```
'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

I have installed @types/node. Why am I getting this error? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You can fix it by either using

`Buffer.from(url, 'base64');`

or

`new (Buffer.from as any)(url, 'base64');`

But, I don't know why this is an issue if you have types installed.

Answer (score 1):

`new` is redundant here, you just need to call `Buffer.from(url, 'base64')`.

There is a deprecated `new Buffer(url, 'base64')` but it's not recommended to use it.